# Why it is not necessary to spread the current state when I handle input change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why it is not necessary to spread the current state (...this.state) when I handle input change in React Class Component? In current state I have other objects

```
handleInputChange = (newValue: string) => {
  this.setState({
      ...this.state, *<--- this string*
      value: newValue,
  });
};
```

Comment: There is another way of invoking `setState` using `this.setState(prevState => {});` and in this case, one may need to spread `prevState`. Link: [React setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged):

> **State Updates are Merged**
>
> When you call `setState()`, React merges the object you provide into
> the current state.
>
> For example, your state may contain several independent variables:
>
> ```
>   constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = {
>       posts: [],
>       comments: []
>     };
>   }
> ```
>
> Then you can update them independently with separate setState() calls:
>
> ```
>   componentDidMount() {
>     fetchPosts().then(response => {
>       this.setState({
>         posts: response.posts
>       });
>     });
>
>     fetchComments().then(response => {
>       this.setState({
>         comments: response.comments
>       });
>     });
>   }
> ```
>
> The merging is shallow, so `this.setState({comments})` leaves
> `this.state.posts` intact, but completely replaces
> `this.state.comments`.